# Angular js: Cannot create property 'type' on string

Tags: angularjs

i want disable image with angular js i used a function to do that i have this error  Cannot create property 'type' on string:

Controller :

```
 $scope.ActivePlaceSpotCAM = function (idPlace, typePlace) {
        var res = null;
        angular.forEach($scope.ListPlaces, function (value, key) {      
            angular.forEach(value.type, function (value ,key) {
                if (value.type = typePlace && value.id == idPlace) {
                    res = value;   
                }

            });
        });
        return res;
    }
```

html :

```
<div class="SvgPicto  col-lg-2  col-md-2  col-sm-2  col-xs-2">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/Common/pic.svg")" ng-init="configuredPlaces[@nbPlace] == place.type" ng-if="ActivePlaceSpotCAM(place.id,place.type)"/>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you an idea please

Comment: You are accidently trying to assign a type variable, guess you want to compare -> `(value.type = typePlace && value.id == idPlace)` should be `(value.type == typePlace && value.id == idPlace)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing assignment operation in if please correct

```
 if (value.type = typePlace && value.id == idPlace)
```

to

if (value.type == typePlace && value.id == idPlace)

And please check the type of value it should not be a string.Before comparing you should check weather the type property is existing or not.

Comment: hello , 
in the html what I put is correct or not please

Comment: Hello neha , yes i tchecked the type . i want to know if what i put in html to disable image is correct or not :)?

Comment: Hello,Your function returns the actual value i.e the object it wont return true or false so i suggest please change the function in such a way that if your condition satisfies then return true else false ,so ng-if="false" will definitely disable your image.